# Topology of étalé space of sheaf of holomorphic functions is Hausdorff

Tags: complex-analysis, sheaf-theory

I want to prove that the topology on $\bigsqcup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{C}^n} \mathcal{O}_z$, where the stalks are germs of holomorphic functions is Hausdorff.

I distinguish two cases:

1. $x \neq y$ lie in different fibers of $\bigsqcup \limits_{z \in \mathbb{C}^n} \mathcal{O}_z$.
   I was able to seperate them without even using that we are dealing with holomorphic functions.
2. $x,y \in \mathcal{O}_{z_0}$ for some $z_0  \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$. Now I can find holomorphic functions $f,g$ on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ containing $z_0$ such  that $f_{z_0} = x$, $g_{z_0} = y$. In particular, $f$ and $g$ must be different on every open set $z_0 \in V \subset U$, otherwise they would be equivalent.

I was told in the proof the Identity Theorem must be used. Probably in its contrapositive form. But I don't see how.

Comment: étalé $\to$ étale

Comment: @JeanMarie: "étalé space" is a standard name for this concept, though it is also sometimes called "étale space" instead.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about what neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ look like in case 2, and what it would mean for such neighborhoods to be disjoint?

Comment: A basis of the topology on the étale space is given by $\{h_x : x \in U\}$ for open sets $U$ and  hol. fcts. defined on $U$. It would make sense to use restrictions of the representatives $f$ and $g$ here. I think their respective stalks must be all different. Otherwise $f$ and $g$ would have to agree on a nbhd. of some stalk. And thus be equal by the identity theorem. Is that correct ?